# Dependent drop-down menu for document column

Tags: 2013, cascading

I'm trying to create mandatory "client" and "matter" columns for documents saved in a Sharepoint 2013 document library, where matters have to be dependent on client (i.e. each client has different matters). Please keep in mind that I am not a programmer or an expert.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use the Sharepoint SPservices , this cascade functionality is supported with SharePoint and works great.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  

          $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({  

            relationshipList: "State",  

            relationshipListParentColumn: "Country",  

            relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  

            relationshipListSortColumn: "ID",  

            parentColumn: "Country",  

            childColumn: "State",  

            promptText: "Choose State...",  

            debug: true     
         });     
});
```

This is the best approach you can find 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/758909/Two-Level-Cascading-Drop-Down-in-SharePoint-using

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I'm not a big fan of cascading columns, as they are not natively supported in SharePoint, but if you need them desperately, you could explore some open packages.

For instance, [SharePoint Cascaded Lookups - JavaScript based](https://spcd.codeplex.com/) is one such. All you need to do is,

1. Create a set of lists for each cascading dropdown you need - where these lists map out the values as they cascade in dropdown
2. Add a few lines of JS to your item edit form via a content editor web part, and configure the parent and child lookup fields

However, the project description page does mention that the tool has been tested with IE and FF, I would still suggest you test it independently on your browsers.

*One critical point to note is that if your end-users are going to use office applications to view/edit the properties of your documents (via document panel) this tool will not work there.*